# How to unmarshall only child elements using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to unmarshall only few children of a large XML using JaxB. XML structure is something like this:

```
<root>
  <child1>
    <child1.1>
       <child1.1.1/>
       <child2.1.1/>
       <child2.1.1/>
       <child3.1.1/>
       <child3.1.1/>
    </child1.1>
   </child1>
</root>
```

Here I want to unmarshall to `child1.1.1, child2.1.1 and child3.1.1`. I dont want to create root element's java class and just want to marshal children.
Right now I am unmarshalling the root element and getting the child objects out of it.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {RootType.class}, null);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
File xml = new File("D:/Projects/test.xml");
RootType root = (RootType)unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
Child1.1.1[] child1.1.1 = root.getChild1().getChild1.1[0].getChild1.1.1()
```

Another issue is dealing with multiple children.
How I am gonna deal with `child2.1.1 and child3.1.1` while unmarshalling individual child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of letting JAXB do the parsing of the file, you could parse it yourself using a `DocumentBuilder` and then extract the nodes you are interested in, for example using XPath. Then you can unmarshal each Node individually using [Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Node node)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28org.w3c.dom.Node%29).